# SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed Even after default value is declared

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-jetpack

In an ongoing android project, almost all database query is written in the old school method. Using `DataHelper` and `DatabaseOpenHelper`.

In this method, all insertion query was working just fine.

As the project is not released yet, there was scope to introduce `Room` ORM for android in it. For some reason, we cannot convert all old database codes to `Room` compatible codes. So, we have decided to create the database with `Room` and keep all old operations in the old school method. And any new operation would be added in `Room` Daos.

For your information, the previous old school model code create table statement is below :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subscriber(
_id integer, 
number text primary key not null, 
name text, 
lookup_key text not null, 
presencestate integer not null default 4, 
presencenote text, 
subscriberimagehash text, 
last_online_time integer default 0, 
isfavourite integer not null default 0, 
buddy_public_key text default '', 
buddy_seed text default '')
```

I have created all entities that would make the same table structure as of the old one. Here is the entity class for the same subscriber table;

```
@Entity(tableName = "subscriber")
public class Subscriber{
    public int _id;

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    public String number = SlothDefault.number;

    public String name;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lookup_key")
    public String lookUpKey = SlothDefault.lookUpKey;

    @Nullable
    @ColumnInfo(name = "presencestate")
    public int presencesState = 4;

    @Nullable
    @ColumnInfo(name = "presencenote")
    public String presenceNote = "";

    @Nullable
    @ColumnInfo(name = "subscriberimagehash")
    public String subscriberImageHash;

    @Nullable
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_online_time")
    public Date lastOnlineTime = new Date(0);

    @Nullable
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isfavourite")
    public boolean isFavorite = false;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "buddy_public_key")
    public String buddyPublicKey = "";

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "buddy_seed")
    public String buddySeed = "";
}
```

Now, come the the problem. This was the code that was working fine previously for 
inserting new subscriber in table:

```
try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NUMBER, number);
        values.put(KEY_ID, ContactEngine.getContactIDFromNumber(context, number));
        String name = ContactEngine.getContactNamefromNumber(context, number);
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name == null ? "" : name);
        values.put(KEY_PRESENCE_NOTE, " ");
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_LOOKUP, ContactEngine.getContactLookupKey(context, number));
        values.put(KEY_PRESENCE_STATE, 4);
        long count = readableDatabase.insert(SUBSCRIBER_TABLE, null, values);
        if (count > 0) {
            context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(SUBSCRIBER_URI, null);
            context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTACTS_URI, null);
            Log.i("datahelper", "subsciber added " + number);
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("DataHelper", "CreateSubscriber: ", e);
        return false;
    }
```

This code was working properly before with old school database creation. But now this code shows the following exception :

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=Mir Monsoor Hossain number=8801811412834 lookup_key=3224i90e3d5809e0669e.3789r2238-41394B044145434D45454B0437454D4D293943.2748r4007-41394B044145434D45454B0437454D4D293943.393i1471.1894r6295-41394B044145434D45454B0437454D4D293943
_id=8540 presencenote=  presencestate=4
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: subscriber.isfavourite (code 1299)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:783)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1548)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1417)
        at com.revesoft.itelmobiledialer.databaseentry.DataHelper.createSubscriber(DataHelper.java:932)
        at com.revesoft.itelmobiledialer.service.DialerService.addSubsriber(DialerService.java:2651)
        at com.revesoft.itelmobiledialer.signalling.SIPProvider$SubscriberProcessorThread.run(SIPProvider.java:12403)
```

I have tried to make the field explicitly nullable but this is not helping.

```
@Nullable
@ColumnInfo(name = "isfavourite")
public boolean isFavorite = false;
```

How to resolve this exception without altering any previous insert statements? And with having a default value for the field?